# Symfony progress bar - simple in green (like <info></>)?

Tags: php, symfony

Using symfony to colorize messages is convinient:

```
$output->writeln('<info>Hello world</info>');
```

What´s the simplest way to set a progress bar into this color scheme. Nothing fancy - no extras: Just to declare the progress bar as an info in standard colors: fg=green bg=black? That´s all

I only found instructions for super fancy customizations - which I don´t need.

My various attempts with using

```
$progress->setFormat();
```

or

```
$progress->setFormatDefinition();
```

were unsuccessful

Answer (score 7):

You can customize the progress bar with the [progress bar component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html#bar-settings)'s methods. To change the color you only need to set the `character`:

```
$progressBar = new ProgressBar($output, $cpt);
$progressBar->setBarCharacter('<fg=green>•</>');
$progressBar->setEmptyBarCharacter('<fg=green>⚬</>');
$progressBar->setProgressCharacter('<fg=green>➤</>');
$progressBar->setFormat($format);
```

The example gives you this:

[image: command with progress bar]

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I asked for. I asked explicitly for an easy way. I just don't want to (re)define every single component. I just want everything that is already defined by default only to be displayed completely as <info>, i.e. green.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty close to what I was looking for:

```
$progress = new ProgressBar($output);
$progress->setFormatDefinition('info', '<info>%current% [%bar%]</info>');
$progress->setFormat('info');
```

Does it get any easier?